# Image located in directory; Image name loaded in MySql. PHP Script is not returning the image

Tags: php, directory, return

I have been trying different things in order to get this script to query the MySql DB for the image name and then go to the directory and return the image with the same name. It seems simple in concept, but I keep getting a bunch of mixed results and none of the results return the image.

Here is the most recent code that I tried:

```
$sqlCar = mysql_query("SELECT img_nm FROM vehicles WHERE sold='n' ORDER BY year DESC");

/***************************
****
Code Returns '1'
******************************/

$dbImage = $sqlCar;
$dirImage = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/car-pics/');

    function imgCompare($dbImage){
    if ($dbImage == $dirImage[img_nm]){
        echo $dirImage[img_nm];
    } else {
        echo "Image Coming Soon";   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not adding $dirImage as a parameter to the function.  You can solve this by adding it as a parameter, or adding the global keyword to the first line of your function like this:

```
function imgCompare($dbImage){
    global $dirImage;

    if ($dbImage == $dirImage[img_nm]){
        echo $dirImage[img_nm];
    } else {
        echo "Image Coming Soon";   
    }
}
```

Also, what values are in img_nm in the database?  scandir uses an array of index values.  So $dirImage[0] would work, but $dirImage['filename.jpg'] would not.

Comment: hmm.. adding it as a parameter and adding the global didn't help. The values being stored in the database are the same as the file names in the directory. So img_nm = vehicle1.jpg & directory is home/car-pics/vehicle1.jpg

Comment: Take a look at antoni's answer.  mysql_query returns a result set resource, and you need to call mysql_fetch_array to get the value from the resource.

Answer (score 0):

The mysql_query function is not going to return the value you are looking for directly into $sqlCar where it is directly accessible.

you will have to do something like

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $sqlCar );
```

And then reference the array to get the image name

```
$dbImage = $row['img_nm'];
```

Comment: Adam is right too. You are not passing $dirImage to the function.

Comment: I tried adding a mysqli_fetch_array to it (mysql_fetch_array deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0), and I keep receiving mysql_result() errors.

Comment: Are you running 5.5? mysql_query is deprecated as well. you need to use mysqli_query() in 5.5. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: I didn't realize that I had mysql_query in the first line. Sorry about the confusion. I think I was over-thinking the solution for the image return, and I decided to go with a completely different solution by inserting     <img src='../car-pics/".$row['img_nm']."'>",     into the while loop